# representing an improper integral as a power series in the lower bound

Tags: calculus, power-series, improper-integrals

> Let $y\in \mathbb{R}$ and $y>1$. How can I prove that: $$\int_{y}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{3}-1}dx=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{y^{1-3n}}{3n-1}?$$

So far, I have rewritten the integrand $\frac{1}{x^{3}-1}$ as a rational function by applying the partial fraction decomposition method. I get the primitive $$\frac{1}{3}\ln|x-1|-\frac{1}{6}\ln(x^2+x+1)-\frac{1}{\sqrt 3}\tan^{-1}(\frac{(2x+1)}{\sqrt 3})$$ at the end. Though, I haven't seen any possibility here to rewrite the primitive function as a power series.

Is there any trick to apply ?

Comment: Your question is in the process of reopening following your edits. Thank you for the additional information. It is recommended that you post any context at the same time as the question is created : this will make sure that you avoid closure and your question remains visible and attractive to a larger crowd, thus attracting good answers. On your attempt : I'm surprised you went for the anti-derivative, because while it did exist, the RHS is given by a series, which upon slight inspection is a modified geometric series, so writing the $x$ term as a geometric series will come to mind.

Comment: If you wish to continue from your attempt, you can do it but you will require power series expansions of each of the primitives and then have to justify recombination. That's possible, and if you are testing your power series basics is an excellent exercise, but it's not the easiest way to answer the question.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon to your remark about the structure of the question: Thanks for the information. I am just new to community, so I will pay attention next time :)

Comment: It's easier than you think to post a good question here, as you have seen! The next time I see you question I am sure it will be good enough to stay on site. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: well it is also possible to derive the power series by using the taylor expansion, if i am not wrong, but that would be too long for the question, as you mentioned. I was just blind to see the trick with finding the equal function by expanding the fraction, but never mind...

Comment: A Taylor expansion is indeed too involved, but for suggesting it, interacting with me and helping open this question, a +1. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick to apply involves writing the function as a sum *before* integrating it. In particular, you can write

$$\frac{1}{x^3-1} = \frac{1}{x^3}\frac{1}{1-x^{-3}}$$

and then use the fact that $$\frac{1}{1-a}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a^n.$$

Substituting $a=x^{-3}$, and joining the equations, gives

$$\frac{1}{x^3 - 1} =  \frac{1}{x^3}\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{-3n} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty{x^{-3n-3}}.$$

It is now a simple matter of changing the integral of a series into a series of integrals.

---

Note that there are some things you should be careful of in the steps I performed above, in particular:

1. The infinite sum $$\frac{1}{1-a}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a^n$$ only holds for $|a|<1$. You must show that this is so in your case.
2. An integral of a series is not always equal to the sum of individual integrals. There are conditions under which the equality holds, and you must show that one such condition is met.